# Managing static files Separately For Media Uploads and Separate for React Build

Tags: python, reactjs, django, google-cloud-storage

I have a little problem with my current Static Files Config.

Current `Settings.py`

```
#...
GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS = BASE_DIR / 'Cloud_Storage_Secrets/model-calling-323507-96957393f399.json'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/images/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR / 'static',
    BASE_DIR / 'build/static' #React Frontend Files
]

MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'static/images'
STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'staticfiles'

GS_BUCKET_NAME = 'GS_BUCKET_NAME'

STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.gcloud.GoogleCloudStorage'
GS_CREDENTIALS = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
    GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS
)
#...
```

Now the problem is that React frontend Build is also considered as static files when Django serves these files. Locally it works fine after creating a build from the `npm run build` command manually. But when I push this in production with two separate engines One `Node.js` for React and the other is Python for Django app on Heroku, then Django tries to get Build files from `GS_BUCKET` as configured for Media files and static files. So frontend build files are not picked by `Django`.

So I'm trying to make two configurations. `Google Cloud Storage` for just media files but Static Files should work as default bypassing `Google Cloud Storage`.

**So How to make it possible. Please suggest to me any method to make them separate. Or how to Bypass `Google Cloud Storage` Config for just Media Files. Thanks!**

> If you need more clarification please comment it out then I'll add more details as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found the solution. It was quite easy, but it took me a lot of time to have this idea configuring this way.
Now I'm using `Whitenoise` to serve all static files coming from React.js Frontend build and also for the Django as well. But `Google Cloud Storage` is just for the Media Uploads.

This is updated settings.py

```
#...
# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/
GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS = BASE_DIR / 'Cloud_Storage_Secrets/model-calling-323507-96957393f399.json'

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'
STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'staticfiles'

MEDIA_URL = '/images/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR / 'static',
    BASE_DIR / 'build/static'
]

MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'images'
GS_BUCKET_NAME = 'buket-name'
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.gcloud.GoogleCloudStorage'
# STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.gcloud.GoogleCloudStorage'
GS_CREDENTIALS = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
    GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS
)
#...
```

> You can check out the live running mock site with this config. on.
> https://naturalmedicineclinic.herokuapp.com/